# GIT: gclient sync error "Needed a single revision"

Tags: git, chromium

I have cloned a newer version of chromium onto my system. I referred this [webpage](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md). I needed an older version so i did `git checkout <version>`. Then i ran `gclient sync` which resulted in an error **Needed a single revision**. I checked and found that this error is produced in this folder `src/third_party/webrtc`. I checked the branch that i did checkout earlier, There was no such folder in that branch, so i tried removing the folder `webrtc` itself from my system and tried running `gclient sync` again. But that resulted in more errors. Also i tried `git rebase -i --root`, still gave me the same error.

How to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: This does seem to be a question related to function of `gclient`, maybe it would be needed to take a deep dive into https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/tools/depot_tools/gclient.py?sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=2502

Comment: Did you try: ``gclient sync --with_branch_heads``? You should do that too to pull other third-party dependencies